# Rescue rake tasks

Tags: ruby, rake

I have a number of file tasks in my Rakefile which look like

```
file 'task1' => 'dep' do
  sh "some command"
end
```

There's also

```
task :start => :next
task :last => :dep2
```

I was wondering if there was a way of rescuing it on the top level, i.e. to say

```
begin
  task :last => :dep2
rescue
  # do something
end
```

rather than in every `file` task do

```
file 'task1' => 'dep' do
  begin
    sh "some command"
  rescue
    # do something
  end
end
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, but you can define a custom method to simplify your tasks.

```
def safe_task(&block)
  yield
rescue
  # do something
end

file 'task1' => 'dep' do
  safe_task do
    sh "some command"
  end
end
```

Also, remember that is `:task2` depends on `:task1` and `:task1` can raise an exception, you should handle the error in `:task1`, not in `:task2`.

Comment: thanks once again, are you aware of any way to hook into the function that renders the stacktrace or something similar?